# Laravel 5 many user roles but 1 login route

Tags: php, laravel-5

i have many user roles such as admin, messenger, cashier and sender

what i did was put them in one table called "users" and just put a role field that would identify them of their roles. But my problem is that each role doesn't have the same field like the messenger have an assigned area field while the sender doesn't have. It should be only 1 login and after logging in, identify the role and direct them to a specific view depending on their roles. Sample if i login as admin then i should be directed to admin's page, if sender then go to sender's page.

What is a good way to do this using Laravel 5 framework and using auth login by laravel?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to achieve this is via custom middleware definition. Check the default auth middleware and design your new middleware similar to that.

Simply if user is logged in, get the user and check his/her role. If he/she has admin privilege, redirect to admin page etc.

After defining this middleware, you can modify your routes and attach this middleware to them.

This is explained in detail [here](http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware)

Comment: that's what i did but my problem is user roles doesn't have the same field.. like messenger doesn't have the same field as admin so putting them in one table doesn't seem right cause then some field will be left empty depending on their roles

Comment: Can you provide some detail on the fields?

Comment: sender has id firstname lastname email password addres contact.
messenger has id firstname lastname email password assignedarea platenumber

Comment: Maybe you define hasOne relation such as hasOne('Address') where you can store address and contact details, and hasOne('Area') where you can store assignedArea etc. You can then control whether user's address or area are null or not.

Comment: i have read about polymorphic.. it really answers my question
but i'm still learning on it though